# Missing "zu" before Infinitive?

Tags: sentence-structure

> Seine Leser hat er begeistert und verärgert, seine Heimat mit Liebe und Spott beschreiben.

I read this sentence in a book section talking about Heinrich Heine. Does this sentence misses zu in the 2. part? Should it be

> Seine Leser hat er begeistert und verärgert, seine Heimat mit Liebe und Spott zu beschreiben.

Comment: Are you sure your quote is "beschreiben" and not "beschrieben"?

Comment: I vote to close, since this is obviously a misreading:  https://books.google.de/books?id=vCTSDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=%22Seine+Leser+hat+er+begeistert+und+ver%C3%A4rgert,+seine+Heimat+mit+Liebe+und+Spott+beschrieben%22&source=bl&ots=PXeVefjr9z&sig=4-LfHfWylxMM9Irabu_hpPtqPas&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisjrio7IfZAhXCI1AKHeTsC60Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Seine%20Leser%20hat%20er%20begeistert%20und%20ver%C3%A4rgert%2C%20seine%20Heimat%20mit%20Liebe%20und%20Spott%20beschrieben%22&f=false

Comment: @tofro yes I revised it and it is beschrieben.Sorry

Comment: What makes it so hard to give a **custom close reason** for cases where our canned reasons won't fit? There is nothing "unclear" with this question. We even have a comment that would perfectly make such a custom reason. See https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/community-moderation-robo-reviews-dont-help-anybody?cb=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

> Seine Leser hat er begeistert und verärgert, seine Heimat mit Liebe und Spott beschr**ie**ben.

That's actually an ellipsis of "hat er" in the second (part of the) sentence (*seine Heimat hat er mit..*); it is a somewhat poetic way of speaking.

Otherwise you are right, with "beschr**ei**ben" the "zu" would be missing. But the sentence does not make sense that way; you would need to alter it completely, e.g. for

> Seine Leser hat er begeistert und verärgert, indem er seine Heimat mit Liebe und Spott beschrieb.